# Which of the games that are included in the Metal Gear Solid Legacy Collection are download codes?

Tags: ps3, metal-gear-solid-legacy-collection

Which games are included in the Metal Gear Solid Legacy Collection as download codes? Given that the collection was released a couple of years back, do those codes have expiration dates?

Comment: I don't have it myself, but some amazon reviews suggest that only MGS1 and "Metal Gear Solid Special Missions" are included as a download code.

Comment: @Kodama yes but what about expiration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Metal Gear Solid Legacy Collection* comes with a single download code for the following games:

- *Metal Gear Solid*
- *Metal Gear Solid VR Missions*

All other games included on the discs within the case.

There is no mention if an expiration date anywhere with the code, so we can assume for now that these codes will function as long as these codes can be distributed and redeemed. If your code happens to not function, I would contact Sony for help.

I have purchased the Legacy Collection within the past month and the code worked perfectly fine, several years after is was released.

Comment: Psn accoun matters? Country i mean